# The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: services.web.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string, or an object

Tags: docker

Below is my yml file
version: '3.8'
services:
web:
build:
ports:
- "5000:5000"
redis:
image: "redis:alpine"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a properly formated file content

Answer (score 1):

you should write yml file more clearly

you wrote down the build option, like build:, but the path to build was not clear

```
version: '3.8' 
  services: 
    web: 
      build: {your build path}
      ports: 
        - "5000:5000"  
    redis: 
      image: "redis:alpine"
```